# Sort an assoc array index into reverse order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Hey guys I hope a very quick one!

I have an array

```
array(
(int) 30 => array(
    'score' => (int) 30,
    'max_score' => (int) 40,
    'username' => 'joeappleton',
    'user_id' => '1'
),
(int) 34 => array(
    'score' => (int) 34,
    'max_score' => (int) 40,
    'username' => 'joeappleton',
    'user_id' => '1'
),
(int) 36 => array(
    'score' => (int) 36,
    'max_score' => (int) 40,
    'username' => 'joeappleton',
    'user_id' => '1'
)
```

)

I need it to be sorted into descending order, by reference of the array key:

```
array( 
    36 => array('score' => 36, 'max_score' => 40, 'username' => 'joeappleton', 'user_id' => '1'),
    34 => array('score' => 34, 'max_score' => 40, 'username' => 'joeappleton', 'user_id' => '1'),
    30 => array('score' => 36, 'max_score' => 40, 'username' => 'joeappleton', 'user_id' => '1')
);
```

I've tried krsort() but no joy, it seems to return a bool. Any ideas?

Comment: high to low or low to high?

Comment: `krsort()` returns boolean, but modifies original array!

Comment: Is there any reason you can't create the array in descending order?  That is, do you need to use it in both orderings (ascending and descending) or only one?

Comment: where are the codes?

Comment: All the sorting functions modify the input array, they don't return a sorted array.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the issue was that krsort(), uses pass by reference. It sorts the original array and returns a bool.

I changed

```
return krsort($returnArray); //this returned true
```

to

`krsort($returnArray);
    return $returnArray;`

Answer (score 0):

we can use array_multisort,which give the same result you want!!!

```
<?php 
$people = array( 
(int) 30 => array(
'score' => (int) 30,
'max_score' => (int) 40,
'username' => 'joeappleton',
'user_id' => '1'
),
(int) 34 => array(
'score' => (int) 34,
'max_score' => (int) 40,
'username' => 'joeappleton',
'user_id' => '1'
),
(int) 36 => array(
'score' => (int) 36,
'max_score' => (int) 40,
'username' => 'joeappleton',
'user_id' => '1'
)); 
//var_dump($people); 

$sortArray = array(); 

foreach($people as $person){ 
foreach($person as $key=>$value){ 
    if(!isset($sortArray[$key])){ 
        $sortArray[$key] = array(); 
    } 
    $sortArray[$key][] = $value; 
} 
} 

$orderby = "score"; //change this to whatever key you want from the array 

array_multisort($sortArray[$orderby],SORT_DESC,$people); 

//var_dump($people); 
print_r($people);
?>
```